# Are there handballs in fifa 17?

Tags: fifa-17

I've noticed that in the time I've been playing fifa 17, there hasn't been a single handball.

Are there handballs in the game and if not, why did fifa choose not to include it?

Answer (score 2):

The rule for handball is turnt off by default, but you can turn it on in the settings.

In my opinion it's not worth to turn it on,  you will encounter several situation you or your opponent gets penalized by this rule without the chance to prevent a handball.
You have no influence on this, so for a competitive game it's very annoying and adds an unnecessary random factor which can lead to a game changing situation e.g. a penalty.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bQdcobgS68) video, there is an option to turn handballs on or off.  That would denote that they do exist.  You've probably not witnessed one yet, or you have them turned off by accident.